# Best way to extract rows from DataTable (based on date field) and copy to another DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq, select, datatable

I have a DataTable containing about 30 rows and I need to extract all rows having a date field bigger than a date stored into a variable.
(This code will be executed a lot of times)

I found three ways to do this but I would like to know how to choose because I don't know the differences between various codes.

Here is what I was able to write (and my worries):

1st way (DataTable.Select)

```
Dim SelectedRows() As DataRow = DT_DBData.Select("In_Date=#" & _
    LastDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "#")
Using New_Dt As DataTable = SelectedRows.CopyToDataTable
    'Some code
End Using
```

I'm worried about the string format: I'm afraid that some rows may be not extracted because of a date formatting error.

2nd way (query Linq)

```
Using New_Dt As DataTable = (From DBData In DT_DBData.AsEnumerable() _
        Where DBData.Field(Of Date)("In_Date") >= LastDate).CopyToDataTable 
    'Some code
End Using
```

I never used Linq and so I don't know what kind of issues can it give me.

3rd way (For Each Loop + If Then)

```
Using New_Dt As DataTable = DT_DBData.Clone
    For Each dr As DataRow In DT_DBData.Rows
        If dr("In_Date") >= LastDate Then
            New_Dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
        End If
    Next
    'Some code
End Using
```

I'm not really worried about this code. I only think that the others could be better or faster (but I can't answer to this)

Comment: Why don´t u create a `Stopwatch`, execute your scenarios and measure the results? Then you´ll have your answer what is "best".

Answer (score 1):

Faster is kind of irrelevant when dealing with 30 rows.

The first one is kind of wasteful.  You start with a `DataTable`, `Select` to get a subset, then convert the result into a new `DataTable`.  Time to extract matching Rows: 8 ms.

You *can* work with the `SelectedRows` array without putting it into a new `DataTable`.  If it goes back to the DB after "some code", I would not extract it from the DT.

By the way, there is no reason to worry about matching date formats as long as the DB column is a date type (and therefore, the `DataTable` column will be also).  Dates *do not* have a format; formats are just how computers (and by extension, us) display them to users.

```
Dim drs = dt.Select(String.Format("StartDate > '{0}'", dtTgt.Date), "")
```

The date type I pass will compare/filter just fine with the `DateTime` data for that column.  Formats only come into play when you convert them to string, which is mostly only needed for those pesky users.

---

One option you missed might be especially useful if this will be done over and over: A `DataView`:

```
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

' create dataview
Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("StartDate > '{0}'", dtTgt.Date)
dv.Sort = "StartDate asc"
' show/iterate/whatever
dgv.DataSource = dv
```

If the data goes back to the DB, using this method, the rows will retain all the rowstate values.

Comment: Thanks for you answer an for your tips. I'll check it. (by now +1) ;)